# Append array values to another array by keys comparison

Tags: php, arrays

I've this two arrays:

```
$arr1['someKey'] = [1,2,3,4,5];
$arr2['someKey'] = [6,7];
```

how do I add|append the values from the second one into the first one by comparing it's keys? The result should be something like:

```
$arr3['someKey'] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
```

Any help?

Comment: What exactly you mean by comparing keys?

Comment: i am not sure what exactly you want but `print_r(array_merge($arr1['someKey'],$arr2['someKey']));` will work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [`array_merge_recursive`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php):

```
$arr1 = array(
    'someKey' => [1,2,3,4,5],
);
$arr2 = array(
    'someKey' => [6,7],
);

$merged = array_merge_recursive($arr1, $arr2);
```

Ideone: http://ideone.com/0wfez8

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

`array_merge_recursive()` merges the elements of one or more arrays together so that the values of one are appended to the end of the previous one. It returns the resulting array.

```
$arr3 = array_merge_recursive($arr1, $arr2);
print_r($arr3);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php

Answer (score 0):

please check on your way should work.

```
$arr3 = $arr1 + $arr2; 

print_r($arr3);
```

as same as array_merge but preserved array keys.