# Optimizing algorithm to avoid exaggerated script execution time

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, optimization

Yesterday I ask here [Append array values to another array by keys comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31933610/append-array-values-to-another-array-by-keys-comparison) and I have tried a few things without success. I have two arrays `$result` and `$result1`. `count($result)` is `204640` and `count($result1)` is `129849` so they are huge. The arrays is the result of a PDO statement execution as shown in code below. This is an example for `$result` array:

```
'00180000015oGSWAA2' =>
    array (
        'accountId' => '00180000015oGSWAA2',
        'npi' => '1053576223',
        'firstname' => 'Jack',
        'lastname' => 'Cheng',
        'title' => '',
        'accountLastModifiedDate' => '2014-09-09 17:37:15',
        'suffix' => '',
        'fax' => '',
        'address1' => '853 N CHURCH ST',
        'city' => 'SPARTANBURG',
        'stateLicensedId' => '31191',
        'state' => 'SC',
        'phone' => '',
        'zip' => '29303',
        'address2' => '',
        'addressLastModifiedDate' => '2014-09-04 08:44:17',
      ),
'00180000015oGeXAAU' =>
    array (
        'accountId' => '00180000015oGeXAAU',
        'npi' => '1629067301',
        'firstname' => 'Fred',
        'lastname' => 'Thaler',
        'title' => '',
        'accountLastModifiedDate' => '2014-09-09 17:36:41',
        'suffix' => '',
        'fax' => '',
        'address1' => '1 PEARL ST',
        'city' => 'BROCKTON',
        'stateLicensedId' => '58249',
        'state' => 'MA',
        'phone' => '',
        'zip' => '2301',
        'address2' => '',
        'addressLastModifiedDate' => '2014-09-04 04:25:44',
      )
```

And this is an example for `$result1` array:

```
'001S000000nBvryIAC' =>
    array (
        'tid' => '04T800000008zySEAQ',
        'acsLastModifiedDate' => '2015-01-06 17:19:48',
      ),
'00180000015oGeXAAU' =>
    array (
        'tid' => '04T800000008zzgEAA',
        'acsLastModifiedDate' => '2015-01-07 04:06:40',
      ),
'001S000000nYWcYIAW' =>
    array (
        'tid' => '04T800000008zySEAQ',
        'acsLastModifiedDate' => '2015-02-25 15:45:01',
      ),
```

As you can see `$result[1]` and `$result1[1]` shares the same keys, right? Ok, then what I need is to push the content of `$result1[1]` on the end of `$result[1]` and getting something like:

```
'00180000015oGeXAAU' =>
    array (
        'accountId' => '00180000015oGeXAAU',
        'npi' => '1629067301',
        'firstname' => 'Fred',
        'lastname' => 'Thaler',
        'title' => '',
        'accountLastModifiedDate' => '2014-09-09 17:36:41',
        'suffix' => '',
        'fax' => '',
        'address1' => '1 PEARL ST',
        'city' => 'BROCKTON',
        'stateLicensedId' => '58249',
        'state' => 'MA',
        'phone' => '',
        'zip' => '2301',
        'address2' => '',
        'addressLastModifiedDate' => '2014-09-04 04:25:44',
        'tid' => '04T800000008zzgEAA',
        'acsLastModifiedDate' => '2015-01-07 04:06:40',
      )
```

Meaning when keys are equal in both arrays then merge or append values from the second one into the first one. Right now my best approach is the following:

```
// PDO statement
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();

// PDO statement
$result1 = $stmt->fetchAll();

foreach ($result as $key => $row) {
    foreach ($result1 as $key1 => $row1) {
        if ($key === $key1) {
            array_push($row, array_shift($row1));
        }
    }
}

var_dump($row);
```

But it takes an eternity due to arrays length, so any advice in how to speedup this?

**UPDATE: almost a solution**

Based on **@decese** solution I have rewrite this a bit so my apologies in first and take a look to this. Now I called arrays as `$oneArr` and `$twoArr` and also I write a small output examples (don't kill me just yet):

```
// var_export($oneArr)
'00180000015oGSWAA2' =>
    array (
        'target_id' => '00180000015oGSWAA2',
        'firstname' => 'Jack',
      ),
'00180000015oGeXAAU' =>
    array (
        'target_id' => '00180000015oGeXAAU',
        'firstname' => 'Fred',
      )

// var_export($twoArr)
'001S000000nBvryIAC' =>
    array (
        'tid' => '04T800000008zySEAQ',
        'acsLastModifiedDate' => '2015-01-06 17:19:48',
      ),
'00180000015oGeXAAU' =>
    array (
        'tid' => '04T800000008zzgEAA',
        'acsLastModifiedDate' => '2015-01-07 04:06:40',
      )
```

This is the ouput I want to achieve, meaning when keys are equal in both arrays then merge or append values from the second one into the first one:

```
'00180000015oGeXAAU' =>
    array (
        'target_id' => '00180000015oGeXAAU',
        'firstname' => 'Fred',
        'tid' => '04T800000008zzgEAA',
        'acsLastModifiedDate' => '2015-01-07 04:06:40',
      )
```

I have this done, again based on first answer which I thanks a lot for clear a bit things to me, with the following code:

```
// Fetch results from first SQL query
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();

// Fetch only two keys from the entire and put them on $oneArr
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $oneArr[$row['target_id']] = [
        'target_id' => $row['target_id'],
        'firstname' => $row['firstname']
    ];
}

// Fetch results from second SQL query
// yes, var names are the same not matter, I will only use one time
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();

// Fetch only two keys from the entire and put them on $twoArr
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $twoArr[$row['target_id']] = [
        'tid'    => $row['tid'],
        'acslmd' => $row['acslmd']
    ];
}

$i = 0;
foreach ($oneArr as $keyOneArr => $valueOneArr) {
    if (array_key_exists($keyOneArr, $twoArr)) {
        array_push($oneArr[$keyOneArr], $twoArr[$keyOneArr]);
        $i++;
    }
}

var_export($oneArr);
```

But result is not the same as I want since I got this:

```
'00180000015oGeXAAU' =>
    array (
        'target_id' => '00180000015oGeXAAU',
        'firstname' => 'Fred',
        0 =>
            array (
                'tid' => '04T800000008zzgEAA',
                'acslmd' => '2015-01-07 04:06:40',
        ),
    ),
```

How I can avoid the extra array on the result array?

**PS:** Times looks good now: *Call time was 00:01:34*

Comment: divide and conquer my friend. Now you have O(n^2). Maybe you can do some optimalisatio in SQL

Comment: Might make more sense to JOIN the queries, if there's already an obvious relation.

Comment: @Robert this is the best I can do with SQL side, I tried to run and get all in one query using JOIN and UNION but it's worst, takes 5 minutes or so in just execute the query

Comment: so maybe use index on colums that you want to join

Comment: @Robert already tried that too, is to much time and is not the optimum way. I prefer to rely on PHP side and try to solve in there rather than JOIN queries and get all results in just one shoot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your arrays are actually indexed by the ids, so do this:

```
foreach ($result1 as $key => $value) {
    if (isset($result[$key])) {
        $result[$key] += $value;
    }
}
```

Of course, doing all this work in the database using a `JOIN` would make the most sense to begin with, if possible.

Comment: Is not possible to JOIN the queries (check my previous comments) and I am not following you at all on your example code, can you explain what are you trying to achieve in there?

Comment: *For each item in `$result1`, see if the key (the primary id) exists in `$result`, and if so, append the values from `$result1` to the matching key on `$result`.*

Comment: `array_push` is not what you want! You want to `+` both arrays, or perhaps `array_merge` them.

Comment: Thx `$oneArr[$keyOneArr] += $twoArr[$keyOneArr]` did the job as you suggested

Answer (score 2):

You could use `array_merge_recursive`

See my working example: http://3v4l.org/hQERW
Note: in the provided data, only `00180000015oGeXAAU` is common to both arrays, so it only merges the values for that key

Basically, just call

```
$result = array_merge_recursive($result, $result1);
```

PHP.net says:

> **array_merge_recursive()** merges the elements of one or more arrays together so that the values of one are appended to the end of the previous one. It returns the resulting array.
>
> **If the input arrays have the same string keys**, then the **values for these keys are merged together into an array**, and this is done recursively, so that if one of the values is an array itself, the function will merge it with a corresponding entry in another array too. If, however, the arrays have the same numeric key, the later value will not overwrite the original value, but will be appended.